# vimrc is not working in AIX

Tags: vim, telnet, aix

I just started to use AIX 7.1(I telnet to it) and the .vimrc I placed in ~ is not working.

The contents of .vimrc:

> set showmode
>
> set number
>
> backspace=2
>
> shiftwidth=8

No mode was shown, no line number too.

I tried to check what is the vimrc it is using with :scriptnames and :version, but it failed with same error( can't tell exact words now because I am not in office ).

How can I make this right?

Comment: Make sure you are using `vim` and not `vi`.

Comment: Oh yes, it is vi and now I know how to fix this!

Comment: @gunbuster363, doesn't need fixing!  ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already stated by gunbuster363:

- He was using AIX standard *vi(1)*
- Solution would be to name the startup file `~/.exrc`